# Grep across multiple lines but returning all matches

Tags: linux, windows, awk, grep, cygwin

I'm trying to grep against a windows file under cygwin or linux, to find all MySQL statements between a table lock and table unlock in a mysql log.

I can use awk, but I need the line numbers from the original file

I don't see why -Pzo isn't working in cygwin

Effectively I'm looking for is a way to locate statements which are prevented from obtaining a lock (where the main query is interrupted)

If I can at least get sensible results from grep then I can then search the results to find entries where something has interrupted the query.

```
    2302221 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
    2302221 Query   SELECT id,startAtom,finishAtom FROM browse_being_allocated WHERE poolID = 31543 AND rushID = '32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff' AND format = 516 AND startAtom <= 1182716 AND finishAtom > 1182716
    2302221 Query   INSERT INTO browse (poolId,atom,skew,format,rushID,start,finish,databytes,srcPoolID,srcAtom,srcSkew,arrived) VALUES (31543,1182716,0,516,'32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff',274545,274588,315392,0,0,0,1)
    2302221 Query   UPDATE browse_being_allocated SET startAtom = 1182717 WHERE id = 26471948
    2302221 Query   UNLOCK TABLES
    2522564 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
    2522564 Query   SELECT id,startAtom,finishAtom FROM browse_being_allocated WHERE poolID = 31543 AND rushID = '32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff' AND format = 516 AND startAtom <= 1182717 AND finishAtom > 1182717
    2522564 Query   INSERT INTO browse (poolId,atom,skew,format,rushID,start,finish,databytes,srcPoolID,srcAtom,srcSkew,arrived) VALUES (31543,1182717,0,516,'32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff',274588,274633,331776,0,0,0,1)
    2522564 Query   UPDATE browse_being_allocated SET startAtom = 1182718 WHERE id = 26471948
    2522564 Query   UNLOCK TABLES
```

The example above would be sensible, and below would represent the first part of a fault condition.

```
            2334151 Change user user@dbsrv1 on db
    2334151 Query   SET NAMES utf8
    2334151 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
    2334151 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
    2302201 Change user user@dbsrv1 on db
    2302201 Query   SET NAMES utf8
    2302201 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
    2302201 Query   SELECT DISTINCT rushID FROM tags WHERE rushID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT rushID FROM essencefragments) GROUP BY rushID
 151216 19:00:39    2566722 Quit
```

I've tried many different ways to get a multiline match, but I've simply not been able to get anything working.  Ideally I'd get it going under cygwin, and I really need to keep the original line numbers so I can jump back to the original logs and tie it up.

Any thoughts?
Cheers

Comment: Have you decontaminated it of all the control-Ms using `dos2unix` or similar first? I can't tell from your question what it is you want to do. Are those 2 blocks of text sample input or output or one of each? Are they desired output or what your current attempt is producing that you don't want. Please tidy up the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: Getting very grumpy that I've tried and failed to edit my post for the last 20 minutes.

$ grep -Ezow "LOCK(.|\s)*UNLOCK" NEWSJBHQDB12A.log > NEWSJBHQDB12A_filtered.txt

I get the start of a lock statement, then every line until ab unlock right at the bottom of the file, so I'm only losing about 150 lines.  If I use -P I get a pcre error.  the top example is sample output, and the bottom part is part of sample input exhibiting the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk should be able to do what you want. I think perl and sed probably would too for that matter.

Using the -E (extended regex) I believe is making your regex too greedy.
As far as why your grep -P is not working, you'll have to use grep --version and grep--help and do some research. Mine is working fine with GNU grep 2.22 on Ubuntu 16.04.

If I understand your question correctly (which I very well may not), you're wanting everything between LOCK and UNLOCK strings. Would this be a viable solution?

```
awk 'BEGIN {ln=1; lck="n"; print "---"};
     lck=="y" {print ln")",$0};
     $3=="UNLOCK" {lck="n"; ln++; print "---"; next};
     $3=="LOCK" && lck=="n" {print ln")",$0; lck="y";ln++; next};
     {ln++};
' NEWSJBHQDB12A.log > NEWSJBHQDB12A_filtered.txt;
```

It should keep track and display the line numbers (var ln) for you to easily reference against your original log file. With the use of the "lck" variable as an on/off switch, it will begin printing when it finds "LOCK" and stop printing when it finds an "UNLOCK."

```
$ cat file
2302221 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
2302221 Query   SELECT id,startAtom,finishAtom FROM browse_being_allocated WHERE poolID = 31543 AND rushID = '32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff' AND format = 516 AND startAtom <= 1182716 AND finishAtom > 1182716
2302221 Query   INSERT INTO browse (poolId,atom,skew,format,rushID,start,finish,databytes,srcPoolID,srcAtom,srcSkew,arrived) VALUES (31543,1182716,0,516,'32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff',274545,274588,315392,0,0,0,1)
2302221 Query   UPDATE browse_being_allocated SET startAtom = 1182717 WHERE id = 26471948
2302221 Query   UNLOCK TABLES
2334151 Change user user@dbsrv1 on db
2334151 Query   SET NAMES utf8
2334151 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
2334151 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
2302201 Change user user@dbsrv1 on db
2302201 Query   SET NAMES utf8
2302201 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
2302201 Query   SELECT DISTINCT rushID FROM tags WHERE rushID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT rushID FROM essencefragments) GROUP BY rushID 151216 19:00:39
2566722 Quit    
2522564 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
2522564 Query   SELECT id,startAtom,finishAtom FROM browse_being_allocated WHERE poolID = 31543 AND rushID = '32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff' AND format = 516 AND startAtom <= 1182717 AND finishAtom > 1182717
2522564 Query   INSERT INTO browse (poolId,atom,skew,format,rushID,start,finish,databytes,srcPoolID,srcAtom,srcSkew,arrived) VALUES (31543,1182717,0,516,'32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff',274588,274633,331776,0,0,0,1)
2522564 Query   UPDATE browse_being_allocated SET startAtom = 1182718 WHERE id = 26471948
2522564 Query   UNLOCK TABLES
```

Test:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {ln=1; lck="n"; print "---"};
     lck=="y" {print ln")",$0};
     $3=="UNLOCK" {lck="n"; ln++; print "---"; next};
     $3=="LOCK" && lck=="n" {print ln")",$0; lck="y";ln++; next};
     {ln++};
' file
---
1)     2302221 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
2)     2302221 Query   SELECT id,startAtom,finishAtom FROM browse_being_allocated WHERE poolID = 31543 AND rushID = '32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff' AND format = 516 AND startAtom <= 1182716 AND finishAtom > 1182716
3)     2302221 Query   INSERT INTO browse (poolId,atom,skew,format,rushID,start,finish,databytes,srcPoolID,srcAtom,srcSkew,arrived) VALUES (31543,1182716,0,516,'32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff',274545,274588,315392,0,0,0,1)
4)     2302221 Query   UPDATE browse_being_allocated SET startAtom = 1182717 WHERE id = 26471948
5)     2302221 Query   UNLOCK TABLES
---
9)     2334151 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
10)     2302201 Change user user@dbsrv1 on db
11)     2302201 Query   SET NAMES utf8
12)     2302201 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
13)     2302201 Query   SELECT DISTINCT rushID FROM tags WHERE rushID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT rushID FROM essencefragments) GROUP BY rushID 151216 19:00:39
14)     2566722 Quit    
15)     2522564 Query   LOCK TABLES browse WRITE, browse_being_allocated WRITE
16)     2522564 Query   SELECT id,startAtom,finishAtom FROM browse_being_allocated WHERE poolID = 31543 AND rushID = '32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff' AND format = 516 AND startAtom <= 1182717 AND finishAtom > 1182717
17)     2522564 Query   INSERT INTO browse (poolId,atom,skew,format,rushID,start,finish,databytes,srcPoolID,srcAtom,srcSkew,arrived) VALUES (31543,1182717,0,516,'32ca680dd0d84f9b9b2945e2186c09ff',274588,274633,331776,0,0,0,1)
18)     2522564 Query   UPDATE browse_being_allocated SET startAtom = 1182718 WHERE id = 26471948
19)     2522564 Query   UNLOCK TABLES
---
```

Simple example:

```
$ cat file 
NO PRINT
NO PRINT
1 Query LOCK
STUFF
STUFF
STUFF
1 Query UNLOCK
NO PRINT
2 Query LOCK
STUFF
2 Query UNLOCK
NO PRINT
NO PRINT
NO PRINT
NO PRINT

$ awk 'BEGIN {ln=1; lck="n"; print "---"};
     lck=="y" {print ln")",$0};
     $3=="UNLOCK" {lck="n"; ln++; print "---"; next};
     $3=="LOCK" && lck=="n" {print ln")",$0; lck="y";ln++; next};
     {ln++};
' file
---
3) 1 Query LOCK
4) STUFF
5) STUFF
6) STUFF
7) 1 Query UNLOCK
---
9) 2 Query LOCK
10) STUFF
11) 2 Query UNLOCK
---
```

Comment: Thank you - sorry, been away and hadn't spotted your response.  It reduces the set size so at least then we can do some more useful analysis.